# Parse JSON Postman response

Tags: json, rest, api, postman

I have a test in Postman where I do a post request and need to parse the json response

The response looks like this:

```
"aPIProxy" : [ {
    "name" : "SFDC-UpdateLoginTime-v1",
    "revision" : [ {
      "configuration" : {
        "basePath" : "/",
        "steps" : [ ]
      },
      "name" : "1",...some attributes}]
```

and i need to get something like :

```
"name" : "SFDC-UpdateLoginTime-v1"
"name" : "1"
```

for a multiple occurrence json file.

Comment: What do you need to do with it once you have the correct format? Store it as a variable or just log it yo the console? Take a look at the  `_. map()` function of lodash to get what you need - https://lodash.com/docs/#map

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The below postman script might help you.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var jsonNamesData = jsonData.aPIProxy;
console.log(jsonNamesData);
var parsedData = "";
for(var i=0;i<jsonNamesData.length;i++){
    parsedData = parsedData +"\"name\" : \"" +jsonNamesData[i].name+"\", ";
    console.log("\"name\" : \"" +jsonNamesData[i].name+"\"");
}
console.log(parsedData);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("parsedNamesResponse", parsedData); // updating parsed data to the environment variable parsedNamesResponse
```

Answer (score 8):

You could capture multiple 'name' properties using the `_.map()` function of Lodash, which is a built it module on the native application. I've had to modify what you need slightly as the `name` key would have been a duplicate.

```
const result = _.map(pm.response.json().aPIProxy, data => ({
  name: data.name,
  revisionName: data.revision[0].name
}))

pm.environment.set("response", JSON.stringify(result))
```

This would then store all the values in an environment variable for you to use elsewhere in another request.

[image: Postman]

Answer (score 0):

You should first parse the response using `JSON.parse`, then you can iterate on the parsed object like:

```
var resObj = JSON.parse(pm.response.text())
for(var i=0; i< resObj.length; i++) {
    console.log("name: "+ resObj[i].name);
}
```