# Need to extract the JSON value from the response using postman is there any way to do this

Tags: json, api, request, postman, response

How to extract the JSON value from the response using postman? Is there any way to do this?
[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried? and add code instead of an image!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON Postman response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025422/parse-json-postman-response)